# Xcode–UITextView text being cut short

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` in my View controller, added from the Interface Builder.

When I disable the "editable" option under "Behavior", some text gets cut from the text view, see screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. It happens when you disable editable. However the entire text that you place in the uitextview will appear.

Comment: Why is that a normal behavior when I disable the editable? I have the same issue in one of my projects. I don't want that the user can change the text. But it getting cutted all the time. Seems to be an iOS bug, isn't it?

Comment: Anyone found a solution?